# Grout or thin set oops

Tags: flooring, tile

Ok I was preparing n my plywood sub floor for ceramic tile I laid concrete board down with thin set and screws the applied tap and grout to seals instead of thin set by mistake , should I try to scrap off all grout and apply thin set or continue with tile installation

Answer (score 1):

If the surface is nice and smooth then go ahead and tile, it makes no difference that you covered the screws with grout instead of thinset. The tiles will bond just fine.

The real reason not to use grout for that purpose is that grout is expensive and thinset is cheap.